# how to concatenate two string and pass in url in ajax call

Tags: javascript, rational-team-concert

I am have one doubt , here is what i am trying out

```
var widgetlink=(window.parent.location.orgin).toString(); //https://www.ajaxcall.com
$.ajax({
            url : widgetlink.concat("/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.rest.IWorkItemRestService/workItemEditableProperties?includeArchived=false&newWorkItem=true&typeId=task&ignoreScriptBasedAttributeAdvisors=true&projectAreaItemId=")
                    + projectAreaContextId
                    + '&projectAreaConfigurationStateId='
                    + paConfigStateIdList,


            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'text/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
```

Here my exceptation is that the full url shall come i.e 
https://www.ajaxcall.com/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.rest.IWorkItemRestService/workItemEditableProperties?includeArchived=false&newWorkItem=true&typeId=task&ignoreScriptBasedAttributeAdvisors=true&projectAreaItemId=_abcdfgr23 ......(rest things)
But the problem is i am not able to use concat method due to which WidgetLink string is not able to concat with rest part.So can anyone help me out here to find out where exactly i am doing wrong

Comment: Why are you trying to use `concat` instead of simple string concatenation via the `+` operator in that place to begin with?

Comment: concat isn't a string function

Comment: @CBore u mean something like  url : widgetlink + "/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.rest.IWorkItemRestService/workItemEditableProperties?includeArchived=false&newWorkItem=true&typeId=task&ignoreScriptBasedAttributeAdvisors=true&projectAreaItemId=")
                    + projectAreaContextId
                    + '&projectAreaConfigurationStateId='
                    + paConfigStateIdList,

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: Write `widgetlink` in lower case when adding suffix material. do not use `concat`, just add the stuff using the `+` operator (which you already do in the argument to `concat` !?)

Comment: @evolutionbox According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat), it is. But it's nonsense to use it here (and probably anywhere else)

Comment: @collapser can you show me how exactly u are telling to write the url?

Comment: better to encode your URL too. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: @collapsar I am honestly surprised.

Comment: @RajatKrishnan I can, but are you really sure that I would do you a favor in doing so ?

Comment: @evolutionbox Happens to me all the time ... ;)

Comment: Still are you getting the same issue after fix it as said by @collapsar

Comment: @collapsar i did the same but still i debugger it shows undefined when i have hover over url

Comment: Use the developer tools the browser furnishes (eg. in Chrome press ctrl-shift-j). Set a breakpoint on your ajax call. Use the browser console to read out values or expressions. replace `widgetlink.concat(...[1]...) + ...[2]...` by `widgetlink + ...[1]... + ...[2]...`.